# How to change change URL string when using ajax?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, url

I have ruby on rails application and I am using a lot of ajax in order to make the web page dynamic and to change only specific part of it.

In some cases, when the page content is changed with ajax, the URL is not changed which I am finding as incorrect and not proper behavior.

For, example:

I have a forgotten password functionally where a email is send to the user with a link for edit. The link looks as follows:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/password_resets/-k63MeQcBkCZt3fovkfsTA/edit
```

and when the user open it and change his password, I am submitting the form with ajax. So, a message that the password is changed and the user can log in now is displayed, but the URL remains the same.

Which is the normal way to fix this in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use something like this in one of your .js files

```
window.history.pushState('object', 'New Title', url);
```

You might want to check out TurboLinks though...does what it seems like you're looking for automatically.

Comment: Thanks, the pushState looks like doing the trick. The TurboLinks are pretty interesting, but can we say they are faster then ajax request - after all the ajax return only part of the page - the turbolinks (as I have read) return the whole page again.

Comment: As I understand it, TurboLinks/PJAX returns the rendered page, without the Layout/Css through Ajax. But if this works...keep using it!

Answer (score 0):

It's the normal behaviour, an ajax call doesn't change the url. If you do that it's not ajax any more, it's just changing the page. But you can:

```
document.location="http://127.0.0.1:8080/password_resets/-k63MeQcBkCZt3fovkfsTA/psswd-Ok";
```

if you want you can just add a hash in the url, and it's still ajax:

```
document.location.hash="psswd-Ok";
```